# Swift 3 - Open URL with PHP in address

Tags: php, swift, url, hyperlink

Trying to open a url with a PHP link in Swift. Doesn't always seem to load properly.

```
    func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.amazon.com/itemxyz&affiliate_id=12345") 
else {
             return //be safe
        }

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
```

Option #2 Type of URL:

```
      func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
            guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.amazon.com?itemxyz&affiliate_id=12345") 
else {
                return //be safe
            }

            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
```

Neither of the URLs trigger consistently to the correct product page or with the proper affiliate tag attached. Is there a special way of opening URLs with PHP in Swift?

Comment: you wanna load this URL in browser or what ?

Comment: Yes, open in Safari from app. The url works, but it drops the PHP sometimes